# $Email->attachments() does not attach file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

We are using Cake's E-Mail class to send emails with attachments. It works fine for all cases except one and we are not able to figure out where the problem is.

Process:

- A pdf-File is created & written to the file-system (file is written correctly and exists)
- when the Email is sent the attachment is 0bytes in size (whereas the file to attach is created correctly in the file-system)

Working code:
`// Write invoice as file`
`$CakePdf->write(APP . 'tmp' . DS . 'invoices' . DS . $invoiceNo . '.pdf');`
`[...]`
`// Send invoice to customer`
`$Email = new CakeEmail('invoice');`
`$Email->attachments(APP . 'tmp' . DS . 'invoices' . DS . $invoiceNo . '.pdf');`
`$Email->to($this->Invoice->Customer->getEmailAdress($customerId));`
`$Email->viewVars(array('invoice_no' => $invoiceNo));`
`$Email->send();`

Not working code (attachment is zero bytes in size):
`$CakePdf->write(APP . 'tmp'. DS .'certificates' . DS . $certLoginId . $certCourseId . '.pdf');`
`[...]`
`// Send certificate to customer`
`$Email = new CakeEmail('certificate');`
`$Email->attachments(APP . 'tmp'. DS .'certificates' . DS . $certLoginId . $certCourseId . '.pdf');`
`$Email->to($emailOfUser);`
`$Email->viewVars(array('courseName' => $certCourseName, 'probandName' => $probandName));`
`$Email->send();`

Edit - there is no typo it is all correctly set. The problem seems to be, that the generation of a PDF by tcpdf runs asycnronously in the background. So when Cake tries to attach the file it is not written to the file system completly. So it cannot be attached.

If tried to let the script sleep for a while with no success:

```
echo '<br>';
echo $path_to_certificate;
echo '<br>';
echo filesize($path_to_certificate);
sleep(10);
echo '<br>';
echo $path_to_certificate;
echo '<br>';
echo filesize($path_to_certificate);
echo '<br>';
sleep(10);
echo $path_to_certificate;
echo '<br>';
echo filesize($path_to_certificate);
```

Outputs:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\eflux_frontend\app\tmp\certificates\13750.pdf
0
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\eflux_frontend\app\tmp\certificates\13750.pdf
0
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\eflux_frontend\app\tmp\certificates\13750.pdf
0
```

Whereas the file is generated in the meantime, because I can see & access the file in the filesystem. It isn't a locking Problem because the other code works in a different place, but the file generated is smaller so it does not take up so much time to process.

How can I now ensure that the generation process is complete?

Comment: What it prints? `APP . 'tmp'. DS .'certificates' . DS . $certLoginId . $certCourseId . '.pdf'`

Comment: Both occurences output the same path - so it should work. [What it actually does now - oO] ...sorry for disturbing.

Comment: "-- Nothing to see here - reported working code as not working --" ... does it mean there's no error or it is resolved and you should delete the question?

Comment: Hang on - please do not delete the question. We are still investigating the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we are not able to ensure, that the PDF is properly created before attaching it to an email (maybe someon can give me a hand here).

Due to the fact, that the created PDF is written to a database an ugly workaround is possible: After the PDF is written to database, we can take it out of the database, write a file using the CakeFileHandler and attach this to the email which works for me:

```
// Workaround
$this->Certificate->recursive = -1;
$data = $this->Certificate->findById($cert_id);
$pdf = base64_decode($data['Certificate']['certificate_pdf']);

$path_to_certificate = APP . 'tmp'. DS .'certificates' . DS . $certLoginId . $certCourseId . '.pdf'; 
$certificate_file = new File($path_to_certificate);
$certificate_file->write($pdf);

[do mail stuff]

$certificate_file->delete();
$certificate_file->close();
```